# Updating parentID in child table and deleting duplicate rows from parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, parent-child

I have 2 **mysql** tables:

**location**

- id_location
- city

**location_geo**

- ip_start
- ip_end
- id_location

The problem is that at least 1/4 of the cities in the **location** table are repeated records. I could easily run this query and delete those repeated records:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE location ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx (city);
```

But **before** doing that, I also have to update the location_geo table with a unique city id.  For instance, this is a possibility:

**location**

- 129, Los Angeles
- 145, New York
- 176, Los Angeles
- 856, Los Angeles

**location_geo**

- 16778240, 16778751, 129
- 16817792, 16819711, 176
- 16820992, 16822527, 129
- 16827904, 16828415, 856
- 16829440, 16832511, 145
- 16832512, 16832639, 129

The id_location field inside the **location_geo** should be updated to the first available ID in the **location** table, so that the results in the example should display:

- 16778240, 16778751, 129
- 16817792, 16819711, 129
- 16820992, 16822527, 129
- 16827904, 16828415, 129
- 16829440, 16832511, 145
- 16832512, 16832639, 129

Btw, there are 2,021,182 records in the **location_geo** table.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in three steps.  You didn't specify your RDBMS type, so this is pretty generic syntax.

Create a mapping table for the new `location_id`:

```
create table new_loc_map as
select a.id_location as old_loc
       a.city
     , b.id_location
from location a
join (
   select city
        , min(id_location) as id_location
   from location
   group by city
   ) b
on a.city=b.city
```

Update the `location_geo` table:

```
update location_geo
from new_loc_map
set location_geo.id_location=new_loc_map.id_location
where location_geo.id_location=new_loc_map.old_loc
```

Create a new `location` table:

```
create table new_location as
(select distinct id_location
      , city
 from new_loc_map
 )
unique index idx (location)
```

Your question describes creating a new composite index on your `location` table to remove duplicates, but unless I don't understand completely, you only need a index on `location_id`.

Comment: hi, the issue is not the duplicate rows, i already have a solution for  that. the issue is to reassign the ids in the child table before deleting repeated rows in the parent table.

Comment: The second step does that, assuming "child table" refers to your `location_geo` table.